# How to get AudioListener.positionX on Safari 13 Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api

Does anyone know what the method of getting AudioContext.listener.positionX is in Safari 13 with the web audio API?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioListener

I am trying to make my app work on Safari, but Safari has not implemented positionX yet. It's just undefined. The only thing I can seem to do on Safari is listener.setPosition(x,y,z).
Any ideas on how to get the current listener position in Safari?
I have tried:

- Listener.pos
- Listener.position
- Listener.X
- Listener.x

And they are all undefined.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioListener#Browser_compatibility) section of that article, you can see that safari actually doesn't support any properties on the audio listener except `speedOfSound` and `doppleFactor`.

As a workaround, you can assume that the position starts at (0,0,0), and then keep track of the position you set every time you call `setPosition`. It's not ideal, but I can't think of a better solution, given safari's implementation of the web audio api.

Comment: Thank you. Why Apple, why do you make our lives so difficult!